# JQuery append all children in parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which will append HTML block on click. I want to append all of it's child elements however it will only append the first child inside the block. How can I append all of it's child elements ?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgykh4dw/)

```
$('#layout-two-columns').click(function() {
       var toAppend=$('#appendTwoColumns').children().eq(0);
       toAppend.clone().insertBefore('#layout-container');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="hidden" id="appendTwoColumns">

<div class="col-md-6 layout-fullwidth text-center m-y-10">
    <p>
     Block 1
    </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 layout-fullwidth text-center m-y-10">
    <p>
    Block 2
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove eq(0) this is only selecting first child of this element which is on 0 index.

```
$('#layout-two-columns').click(function() {
       var toAppend=$('#appendTwoColumns').children();
       toAppend.clone().insertBefore('#layout-container');
});
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Remove eq(0) form **var toAppend=$('#appendTwoColumns').children().eq(0);**

The corrected code: 
**var toAppend=$('#appendTwoColumns').children();**, and  you are good to go.

Note: Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.